# Regexextract numbers from string

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regexextract

I have a regexextract formula which takes the year from Column A (column) - however this only works if the year is yyyy-yy format - however some of the years are only yyyy and it returns an error

Is it possible for the formula to regextract yyyy too?

Essentially only want numbers from products corresponding to their years - not numbers later in the string

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wlI47SEdiAjuY1xgSwIMnUqecbcwfADBuKWp2GtmZ_o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: magelincs, give us the access authorization

Comment: Apologies - have changed permissions now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add a question mark, like this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\d+-?\d+")
```

you could make an array for that formula with:

```
=index(if(A2:A<>"",REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\d+-?\d+"),))
```

if instead you prefer to get exclusively the year

```
=index(if(A2:A<>"",REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\d+"),))
```

Comment: Ah fantastic - thanks a lot!